# Formulas in excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

Can someone help me to understand how I can translate my excel formula to SQL format. Below are the formulae I am using in excel:

```
=IF(AND(R2>0.1,R2<=25),"0-25M",IF(AND(R2>25,R2<=50),"25-50M",IF(AND(R2>50,R2<=75),"50-75M",IF(AND(R2>75,R2<=100),"75-100M",IF(AND(R2>100,R2<50000),"100+M","")))))
```

Much appreciated your help guys

Comment: I don't know excel much, conditions can be written like this in oracle: where R2>0.1 and R2<=25

Answer (score 0):

If/else logic in sql is generally done with a case construct

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN something THEN this
WHEN somethingElse THEN that
etc
ELSE a default value END aliasName
```

Everything in capitals is a keyword and you need all of them.